# I am making an online exam system in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing an exam system in codeigniter. My database has table called questions which has 7 cols question, option1,2,3,4, correct answer and tag. I want to fetch and match results.

My view coding is

```html
<form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>main/economics_validation" name ="f" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
              <?php
              
              foreach($eco as $economics) 
                    {
                ?>
       <li>
            <h3><p>Q<?php echo $economics->id ?>  <?php echo $economics->question; ?></p></h3>
            <p><?php echo $economics->option1 ?>
            <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $economics->id ?>" value="<?php echo $economics->option1 ?>"></p>
            <p><?php echo $economics->option2 ?>
            <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $economics->id ?>" value="<?php echo $economics->option2 ?>"></p>
            <p><?php echo $economics->option3 ?>
            <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $economics->id ?>" value="<?php echo $economics->option3 ?>"></p>
            <p><?php echo $economics->option4 ?>
            <input type="radio" name="<?php echo $economics->id ?>" value="<?php echo $economics->option4 ?>"></p>
       </li>
        <?php 
                  }
        ?>
            
        
    </ul>
    </div>
```

and my controller coding is

```
public function economics_validation()
    {
        $result['d']=$this->model_db->calculate_marks();
        $this->load->view('marks',$result);
    }
```

and my model coding is

```
public function calculate_marks()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM questions");
        $a = $query->result();
        $q2 = $this->db->get('questions');
        $marks = 0;

            foreach($a as $corr)
            {
                for($i = 1; $i <= $q2->num_rows();$i++)
                {
                    if($corr->correct_answer == $this->input->post($i))
                    {
                        $marks = $marks + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }

            }


        return $marks;
    }
```

I'm unable to get the correct result. The problem is that it is telling incorrect answer as correct.

Comment: can you show me what the result var_dump($corr->correct_answer) and var_dump($this->input->post($i)) ? after if statement

Comment: yes here is the output

Comment: string(13) " Luca Pacioli" string(13) " Luca Pacioli" string(14) " Communicating" string(14) " Communicating"   string(9) " Analysis" string(9) " Analysis"

Comment: can you please share your email so that i can contact you. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in your model needs some tweaks. Try this code.

```
public function calculate_marks()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM questions");
        $a = $query->result();
        $marks = 0;

            foreach($a as $corr)
            {
                if($corr->correct_answer == $this->input->post($corr->id))
                {
                    $marks = $marks + 1;
                }

            }

        return $marks;
    }
```

That's all.

Comment: and one thing more i want to add negative marking too for wrong answer but if question is unattempted then 0 mark is given and if answer is wrong then -0.25.

Comment: use this code inside the `foreach`

`        if($this->input->post($corr->id))
         {  
               if($corr->correct_answer == $this->input->post($corr->id))
                {
                    $marks = $marks + 1;
                }
                else 
                {
                    $marks = $marks - 0.25;
                 }
       } `

Comment: Well its not working fine as if i have 5 questions i make all five correct, then the score is 3.5, which should be 5?? please help..